# RunMongoAggregation not working on Apache Nifi. It keeps running but not giving out any output

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I have a process in my nifi data flow which merges two collection using $lookup.

I am using RunMongoAggregation for that, but it seem the Processor is not working even though I have all the properties set correctly. I am not getting any errors. 
The process keeps running but not fetching anything.
[Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zUX6.png)

Following are the properties for RunMongoAggregation:
[Properties for RunMongoAggregation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp1Zm.png)

Here is the $lookup Query:

```
[
{
 "$lookup":
   {
     "from": "crmAccount_Street",
     "localField": "accountid",
     "foreignField": "accountid",
     "as": "streetAddress"
   }
```

}
]

Please help.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Hey, No I wasn't able to make it work therefore I switched to SSIS and used the CDATA packages for Aggregation.